# How to add table rows from text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm extremely new to jquery/html and want to make a diary that I can use to store my long distance running times in a table .

This is my HTML code:

```
<head>

<title>Running Diary</title>
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href= "running.css"/>
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src ="running.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<!-- Title at the top of page !-->
    <h1 id = "title"> Running Diary </h1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<!-- Table containing text/date fields and the entries for a running diary. !-->
    <table id = "diary">

<!-- Column titles for the running diary !-->
        <thead id = "diaryHeader">
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Distance Ran (KM)</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            </th>
        </thead>

<!-- The table row that contains the text field and enter button for adding each entry to the diary !-->
        <tbody>
            <tr id = "diaryFields">
                <td> <input type="date" id="dateField"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="distanceField" placeholder="Distance"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="timeField" placeholder="HH:MM:SS"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="Add" id="diarySubmit"/>

            </tr>

</table>
```

I want the submit button to add a new table row onclick, with the values of the text/date fields as the new table row's data. what is the code to do that?

I have no idea, this is all I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(#"diarySubmit").onclick(function(){

    var distanceRan = document.getElementByName("distanceField").value;
    var timeRan = document.getElementByName("timeField").value;
    var dateRan = document.getElementByName("dateField").value;
});
});
```

Comment: I dont see any `alert`. Where was the alert supposed to show up? Also, i see 2 issues -no jquery reference in the code . Also, `$(#"diarySubmit").onclick()` should be `$("#diarySubmit").click()`

Comment: The event is `click` not `onclick`

Comment: It's important to develop JavaScript with your browser's error console open. It would be complaining about that syntactic problem in `$(#"diarySubmit")`

Comment: @karthikr No jquery reference? 

and thanks all.

Comment: You need to include `jquery` in the html document for all jquery code to work.

Comment: @karthikr can i load jquery and javascript from the same javascript  document?

Comment: I dont know what you mean - jquery, is javascript. You need to add jquery reference to the html in order for it to work : http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: You do realize that this "diary" is going to be reset to zero every time you load the page, right?

Comment: Oh i thought that is what this "<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src ="running.js"></script>" did

Comment: @Jackulus: *"can i load jquery and javascript from the same javascript document?"* JavaScript is a language, one that is understood by web browsers. jQuery is a library of functions *written* in JavaScript. jQuery is not built-in, you have to include it.

Comment: @david yeah I know it will at the moment, i'm hoping to learn how to connect it to databases later.

Comment: @Jackulus: No, that's loading *your* JavaScript.  Your JavaScript relies on jQuery, which is a separate script.  You need to load that one first before you load yours.

Comment: @David thanks, I don't THINK codeacademy went over that, I feel like I missed a huge step or something, thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `getElementBy...` the correct one would be `getElementbyId`. However, if you're using Jquery, you should use syntax similar to `$('#dateField').val()`.

SO can be a tough place when you're new to coding. You should go carefully through the docs of Jquery

Here is something to start with in solving your problem:

First, include Jquery in your HTML `head` as follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src ="running.js"></script>
```

The next part is your Jquery snippet that will take the details from the text boxes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#diarySubmit").on('click', function(){ //This handles the click function for diarySubmit button
        var distanceRan = $('#distanceField').val(); //Taking values from each textbox
        var timeRan = $('#timeField').val();
        var dateRan = $('#dateField').val();
        var new_row = '<tr><td>'+distanceRan+'</td><td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td></tr>'; //creating the new row of to be added
        $('table#your-table').append(new_row);
    });
});
```

However, do go through the syntax and other documentation of JQuery from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/). You can start with learning what `.click()`, `.on()`, `.val()`, `.append()` do in the code above. Hope I helped. Start learning and reading the docs, you'll love JQuery.

Edit: For your question in the comments, this is what you must do:

```
$('tr').on('#clearRow', 'click', function(){
    //Add code to remove row
});
```

This is done because `clearRow` is a dynamically added element which is not present when the DOM gets `ready`. Hence you must use the `.on()` function as mentioned when adding click handlers to a dynamically added element.

Comment: thanks man, is "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" that just a library full of jquery commands?

Comment: Yes, it is the entire Jquery library as developed by them

Comment: if I added this code to the end of the new_Row variable:
var new_row =  '<tr><td>'+distanceRan+'</td><td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td>'+'<td>'+'<button id="clearRow">Clear Entry'+'</button></td></tr>'

Would I be able to use the new button to remove the table row which the button sits on?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

### Demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/4qbac7b4/)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#diarySubmit').click(function () {
        var distanceRan = $("#distanceField").val();
        var timeRan = $("#timeField").val();
        var dateRan = $("#dateField").val();
        $('#diary').append("<tr>" + "<td>" + dateRan + "</td>" + "<td>" + distanceRan + "</td>" + "<td>" + timeRan + "</td>" + "</tr>");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="diary">
    <!-- Column titles for the running diary !-->
    <thead id="diaryHeader">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Distance Ran (KM)</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <!-- The table row that contains the text field and enter button for adding each entry to the diary !-->
    <tbody>
        <tr id="diaryFields">
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="dateField" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="distanceField" placeholder="Distance" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="timeField" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" id="diarySubmit" />
        </tr>
</table>
```

Make sure you add a link to jQuery CDN, to do that add the following line in your `<head></head>` tags before you include your `running.js`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Wow that site is great as well, thanks for that link and the help, Another question if I may; Is there an 'input type' that stores time in the format which I put in the placeholder for "timeField"?

Comment: Okay give me couple minutes, I'll update my answer, so that you won't have to enter the Date. Javascript will do it for you.

Comment: Check out the edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/4qbac7b4/1/embedded/result/). Now you won't have to insert the date. It will automatically add the current date and time. Let me know if you want something more.